# Get list of badges on this site that nobody received yet

Tags: code-golf, stack-exchange-api

Make a code that gets list of [badges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges) that nobody received yet (for example, by using this [website API for badges](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges)), and output the sorted list of such badges, with new line after each.

Example output (may be smaller, depending on when you do this challenge):

```
Archaeologist
Caucus
Constituent
Copy Editor
Deputy
Electorate
Epic
Generalist
Hacker
Legendary
Marshal
Outspoken
Research Assistant
Sheriff
Steward
Strunk & White
Tenacious
Unsung Hero
```

Smallest code wins.

Comment: nice idea, also suspect [data.se] could do it (no answers on that so far) in fact maybe the web query is doing a SQL query at heart...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## JavaScript with jQuery (loaded onto SE sites by default), 58

```
$('.badge',$('.badge-count:not(:has(*))').parent()).text()
```

Must be run on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges. ;)

Strictly conforming output, 116 chars:

```
[].join.call($('.badge',$('.badge-count:not(:has(*))').parent()).map(function(){return $(this).text()}).sort(),'\n')
```

Screenshot of console output (click to enlarge):

[image: screenshot of console output]

Comment: Is using external libs allowed?

Comment: @Ultra jQuery is loaded onto SE sites by default.

Answer (score 6):

**Bash, 173 characters**

```
curl "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/badges?page="{0..50}"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=type&site=codegolf"|gunzip|grep -Po '{"name".*?award_count":0.*?}'|cut -d'"' -f 4
```

Though you could probably shave some characters off by using url shortening.

**WARNING:** Note that running this script a couple of times *will* result in this:

```
{"error_name":"throttle_violation","error_message":"too many requests from this IP, more requests available in 84495 seconds","error_id":502}
```

**Output for codegolf.SE:**

```
code-golf
Informed
Research Assistant
Caucus
Constituent
Outspoken
Deputy
Vox Populi
Excavator
Analytical
Self-Learner
Hacker
Beta
Legendary
Electorate
Investor
Tenacious
Unsung Hero
```

EDIT: tweaked it a bit.

Comment: Bash - huehuehue. PS is `/dev/null` really needed here?

Comment: You can use `curl` instead of `wget -O-`.

Comment: Hmm I thought that I had removed the /dev/null which I had for testing.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP - <del>92</del> 86 characters

```
<?=html_entity_decode(substr(file_get_contents("http://tinyurl.com/q9zlwfr"),12937,190));
```

Inspired by Victor's solution. Very volatile.

Answer (score 0):

## Java - <strike>280</strike> <strike>267</strike> 260

```
class A{public static void main(String[]z)throws Exception{String s="";int y;java.io.InputStream x=new java.net.URL("http://tinyurl.com/q9zlwfr").openStream();while((y=x.read())!=-1)s+=(char)y;System.out.println(s.substring(12937,13126).replace("amp;",""));}}
```

Comment: That seems... volatile. If Stack Exchange team would make almost any change to their website (or if my question would be modified), it would return the wrong list. Besides, the list may be not up to date.

Comment: Why is the class name so long? Why is the argument to `main`'s name so long? Why is there unnecessary whitespace after `InputStream`?

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Well noted. These one slipped when I was converting the ungolfed version to a golfed one.

Comment: @xfix Yeah, very volatile. That was intentional.

Comment: I'm tempted to edit the question by one letter just to troll you :-D

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow :-D